# Resize a circle in openGL keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: c++, opengl, reshape, orthographic

I wrote this code that prints a circle. The problem comes when I try to resize the window. The aspect ratio is not kept and the circle becomes an oval.

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1415

const float DEG2RAD = 3.14159 / 180;
// Keep track of windows changing width and height
GLfloat windowWidth;
GLfloat windowHeight;

void drawCircle(float radius)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
        double angle = 2 * PI * i / 300;
        double x = radius * cos(angle);
        double y = radius * sin(angle);
        glVertex2d(x, y);
    }
    glEnd();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Save the matrix state and do the rotations
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glPushMatrix();
    glColor3d(1, 0, 0);


    drawCircle(100);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}





///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the 
// rendering context. 
void SetupRC()
{
    // Light values and coordinates
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  // Hidden surface removal

    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
}


void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
    GLfloat aspectRatio;
    GLfloat nRange = 200.0f;
    // Prevent a divide by zero
    if (h == 0)
        h = 1;

    // Set Viewport to window dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Reset coordinate system
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // Establish clipping volume (left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
    aspectRatio = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h;
    if (w <= h)
    {
        glOrtho(-nRange, nRange, -nRange*aspectRatio, nRange*aspectRatio, -nRange*2, nRange * 2);
    }
    else
    {
        glOrtho(-nRange /aspectRatio, nRange /aspectRatio, -nRange, nRange, -nRange * 2, nRange * 2);
    }

    // Specify the orthographic (or perpendicular) projection, 
    // i.e., define the viewing box.

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}





///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Entry point of the program
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("Circle");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);

    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

That's the code. I think that the problem is in the `ChangeSize()` function. Can someone help me? I tried dividing and multiplaying the range by the aspect ratio defined as width/height by the problem remains.

Comment: The problem is that you are confusing the aspect ratio of the *circle* with that of the *frustum*. If the aspect ratio of the frustum stays constant then that of the viewport (the destination window area) must change *relative* to it, which means that the image becomes compressed / stretched.

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I can't understand why. Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. The projection matrix transforms from view space to the clip space. 
The coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) in the range (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates.

At Orthographic Projection the coordinates in the eye space are linearly mapped to normalized device coordinates and the clip sapce coordinates are equal the normalized device coordiantes, because  the `w` component is 1 (for a carthesian coordinate).

[image]

Orthographic Projection Matrix:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far 

2/(r-l)         0               0               0
0               2/(t-b)         0               0
0               0               -2/(f-n)        0
-(r+l)/(r-l)    -(t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    1
```

Lets assume you have a full HD window:

```
w = 1920.0;
h = 1080.0;
```

The window has an aspcet ratio of 1.77778

```
aspectRatio = w / h = 1.77778
```

If you set up an orthographic projection matrix like this:

```
glOrtho(-nRange*aspectRatio, nRange*aspectRatio, -nRange, nRange, -nRange*2, nRange*2 );
```

this will result in the following orthographic projections matrix (1.0 / 1.77778 == 0.5625):

```
0.5625/nRange   0            0.0          0.0
0.0             1.0/nRange   0.0          0.0
0.0             0.0          0.5/nRange   0.0
0.0             0.0          0.0          1.0
```

When a geometry is drawn, then each point of the geometry is transformed by the projection matrix. If a circle is drawn in the XY-plane of the viewport,
then the **X-coordinate** is scaled by **0.5625/nRange**:

```
X' = X * prjMat[0][0] = X * 0.5625/nRange
```

while the **Y-coordinate** is scaled by **1.0/nRange**

```
Y' = Y * prjMat[1][1] = Y * 1.0/nRange
```

This means, the orthographic projection matrix applies the reciprocal aspect ratio of the viewport to the geometry, when the geometry is transformed from view space to normalized device space.
This causes that the perfect circle is distorted to an ellipse, in normalized device space and looks like this:

[image]

If you stretch this ellipse back to the rectangular viewport, the you can see the perfect circle in the window or on the screen:

[image]